# How to set column width in a html table with boostrap 4 and html helpers?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple table with 2 columns and an extra one just to add a button in td elements of body:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="table-info">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the visual result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4itK.png)

But I want the first column to be much smaller than the second, like 25% of the table, or something around that. I have tried to set the **th** element to that value, but the result remains the same. Something like:

```
<th class="text-center" style="width:25%;">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
</th>
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 + MVC + Razor

I think the main problem it's on the asp.net html helpers. How can I accomplish the expected behaviour, please?

Comment: Hope handling table's column using `Bootstrap` would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to design table and handle columns using [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp)

else suggest to design table using `Bootstrap`, so you can utilize power of `Bootstrap`

[image: Tables Design Using Bootstrap]

Using `Bootstrap 4` source is :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
 <div class="table col-12 mt-3 pt-2">
  <div class="row table-info">
   <div class="col-3 font-weight-bold text-center py-2">
    Code
   </div>
   <div class="col-7 font-weight-bold text-center py-2">
    Name
   </div>
   <div class="col-2 font-weight-bold text-center py-2">
    Action
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-around py-2">
   <div class="col-3">
    <input type="text" class="h-100 w-100 px-2 border border-dark" value="User1" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-7">
    <input type="text" class="h-100 w-100 px-2 border border-dark" value="User2" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
    <div class="btn btn-success w-100 text-center">Save</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-around py-2">
   <div class="col-3">
    <input type="text" class="h-100 w-100 px-2 border border-dark" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-7">
    <input type="text" class="h-100 w-100 px-2 border border-dark" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
    <div class="btn btn-danger w-100 text-center">Delete</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope working in `Bootstrap` way would help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @AriMustafa, this puts me on the right track. Got to explore bootstrap more in deep.